# Browsers force HTTPS for my NGINX server serving a .app domain

Tags: http, nginx, https

I am creating the NGINX configuration for my website, and, I want to surf to it with Firefox or Chrome, and they always redirect to HTTPS.

I previously had HTTPS enabled for the domain (automatic redirect configured by certbot) but I discarded that configuration to start fresh. The only 'browser' it works with is Postman.

Here is my configuration file:

```
# Setup for the mybarber.app domain. It serves a static frontend and a REST api.
# The domain should only be available on HTTPS and HTTP will be redirected.
# Certificates managed by Let's Encrypt.


# The config for the static frontend.
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name mybarber.app;

    location / {
        root /var/www/mybarber_app;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }
}

# The config for the REST api.
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name api.mybarber.app;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm listening for HTTP. The nginx.conf file is the standard one from the installation. From what I can see, the browser is replacing HTTP with HTTPS even before it asks the server something. Otherwise I would see some kind of redirect in the dev console.

The NGINX server is also not receiving anything. It was suggested on Google that I right click on the history for my domain and click "forget this website" but it doesn't seem to help. My current guess is that the permanent redirect is still somehow in effect. But I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not nginx, but your browsers.
They probably cached the fact that your domain can be accessed via https (because in the past that happened) and so they keep preferring https over http for security reasons.

Try accessing your domain with a private session in your browser or from another computer that never visited your domain before.

If the error persists, you probably had HSTS enabled and this makes harder for you to make your browser forget about it.

If this is the case, try following the instructions from this link in order to reset the HSTS cache: https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/clear-hsts-settings-chrome-firefox

Please be aware that some TLDs, such as .app for instance, are https only. Check https://hstspreload.org/?domain=mybarber.app for example

Comment: Having looked at HSTS a bit more per your suggestion, I discovered that the TLD `.app` is forcefully preloaded with HSTS (https://hstspreload.org/?domain=mybarber.app). To own a domain with this TLD, it is required to serve it over HTTPS. Thanks! Perhaps include this in your answer and I will mark it as the correct answer.